# How to get the value of a text box in MFC when the text box contains a float value

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I am doing a program in MFC and I have come up with an issue. I have a text box created by using the toolbars in Visual Studio.

My text box ID is `IDC_TEXT1` and I need to get the value from the text box (**`float`** value *not* **`string`**). How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of by calling `GetDlgItemText` and `std::stod` like in this example:

```c
class CAboutDlg : public CDialogEx
{
    CString m_txt;
    double m_num;
public:
    CAboutDlg() noexcept;

// Dialog Data
#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
    enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };
#endif

protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

// Implementation
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedOk();
};

CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() noexcept : CDialogEx(IDD_ABOUTBOX)
{
}

void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAboutDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDOK, &CAboutDlg::OnBnClickedOk)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

// App command to run the dialog
void CSO55114372App::OnAppAbout()
{
    CAboutDlg aboutDlg;
    aboutDlg.DoModal();
}

// CSO55114372App customization load/save methods

void CSO55114372App::PreLoadState()
{
    BOOL bNameValid;
    CString strName;
    bNameValid = strName.LoadString(IDS_EDIT_MENU);
    ASSERT(bNameValid);
    GetContextMenuManager()->AddMenu(strName, IDR_POPUP_EDIT);
    bNameValid = strName.LoadString(IDS_EXPLORER);
    ASSERT(bNameValid);
    GetContextMenuManager()->AddMenu(strName, IDR_POPUP_EXPLORER);
}

void CSO55114372App::LoadCustomState()
{
}

void CSO55114372App::SaveCustomState()
{
}

// CSO55114372App message handlers

void CAboutDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT2, m_txt);
    std::wstring s((LPCTSTR)m_txt);
    m_num = std::stod(s);
    CDialogEx::OnOK();
}
```

Comment: thanks for help.but  m_num = std::stod(s); didn't work for me so i wrote this instead  (double) _wtof(s.c_str());

Comment: You are welcome. You can also use std::stof() but it works for you that is great!

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to show you a **second way** of mapping a edit control to a `float` value. This is by using the [ClassWizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/mfc-class-wizard?view=vs-2017).

- **Right-click** the control and choose **Add Variable...**:

[image: Add Variable]

- Set the variable *category* as **value**, the *access* to **private**, specify the **name** and finally set the *variable type* to **`float`**.

[image: Set as float]

- Click **Next** (if required) and set the **numeric range** for input.

[image: Numeric range]

- Click **Finish**

---

Look at the [`DoDataExchange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/dialog-data-exchange?view=vs-2017) method. It will look something like this:

```c
void CMFCApplication2Dlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_fValue);
    DDV_MinMaxFloat(pDX, m_fValue, 1, 100);
}
```

Whenever you need to work with the current value of the edit control, you type `UpdataData(TRUE);` This synchronises the **variable** with the contents of the **edit control**. An example with a break-point in debug mode:

[image: Results]

Comment: in your answer how can i set the value of the text box to zero when i click a button?my text box name is m_txt1

Comment: You simply assign the variable a value of zero and then call UpdateData(FALSE) which will update the control.

Comment: i tried using like this `m_txt1.SetString(0)` and added `UpdateData(FALSE)`but it's not working

Comment: No. Remember that we have mapped the control to a float variable. You assign the float variable the value 0.

Comment: i done this `GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDITZIMAGE, m_txt3);
    std::wstring s3((LPCTSTR)m_txt3);
 zvaluebox =(double) _wtof(s3.c_str());` then i tried this `zvaluebox=0` and updated but still no changes.

Comment: Sorry but you are mixing your answers. The code you show relates to the first answer you accepted. They are two different approaches.

Comment: sorry for that.i will try your suggession

Comment: `m_txt3.Format(_T("%f"), 0.0)` That will convert a `float` to a string. But as mentioned you should have asked those comments on the other answer and not mine. Also, if both of our answers have been useful them please consider upvoting both of them.

Comment: i got the answer already sir.and thank you for all your help.i did it based on your advice and i got the resullt thank you.

Comment: @Ria I am afraid I can't help you with that. You must have something going on with your code and without seeing it .... I suggest you start a new question and try to supply a minimum verifiable example.